# Want to display images from API into 3 columns

Tags: css, reactjs, api, bootstrap-4

I am pulling images from an API and wanted to beautifully display them in the browser in 3 columns. But I have 1 column after using react semantic UI of `Grid` and react-boostrap element of `CardColumns`
[image: Screenshot of how it displays in the browser]

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Grid, Container } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { CardColumns } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import { fetchMealsStartAsync } from '../actions/getMeals';

const MealList = (props) => {
  const { cat } = props;
  const meals = useSelector((state) => state.meals.meals);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchMealsStartAsync(cat));
  }, [cat]);

  return (
    <Container textalign="center" style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.Row>
          {
            meals && meals.map((meal) => (
              <CardColumns
                key={meal.strMeal}
                style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
                as={Link}
                to={{
                  pathname: `/ingredients/${meal.idMeal}`,
                  id: meal.idMeal,
                }}
              >
                <Card className="m-2 pb-1" style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                  <Card.Img variant="top" src={meal.strMealThumb} />
                  <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>
                      {meal.strMeal}
                    </Card.Title>
                    <Button variant="primary">
                      Get Recipe
                    </Button>
                  </Card.Body>
                </Card>
              </CardColumns>
            ))
          }
        </Grid.Row>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
};

MealList.propTypes = {
  cat: PropTypes.string,
};

MealList.defaultProps = {
  cat: '',
};

export default MealList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this put your three(or maybe more) fetched items in a parent div(e.g container) and using css selector give that parent div `display: flex; flex-direction: row;`

Answer (score 0):

I changed  `<Grid.Row>` to  `<Grid.Column>` and added bootstrap to it as follows: `<Grid.Column className="d-flex flex-wrap">`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can simply make 3 column in browser display by putting
i.e.

```
<Grid columns={3}>
      <Grid.Column>
        <Segment>Content</Segment>
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column>
        <Segment>Content</Segment>
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column>
        <Segment>Content</Segment>
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column>
        <Segment>Content</Segment>
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column>
        <Segment>Content</Segment>
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column>
        <Segment>Content</Segment>
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>
```

or replace whole code with this

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Grid, Container } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { CardColumns } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import { fetchMealsStartAsync } from '../actions/getMeals';

const MealList = (props) => {
  const { cat } = props;
  const meals = useSelector((state) => state.meals.meals);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchMealsStartAsync(cat));
  }, [cat]);

  return (
    <Container textalign="center" style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.Row columns={3}>
          {
            meals && meals.map((meal) => (
             <Grid.Column>
              <CardColumns
                key={meal.strMeal}
                style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
                as={Link}
                to={{
                  pathname: `/ingredients/${meal.idMeal}`,
                  id: meal.idMeal,
                }}
              >
                <Card className="m-2 pb-1" style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                  <Card.Img variant="top" src={meal.strMealThumb} />
                  <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>
                      {meal.strMeal}
                    </Card.Title>
                    <Button variant="primary">
                      Get Recipe
                    </Button>
                  </Card.Body>
                </Card>
              </CardColumns>
              </Grid.Column>
            ))
          }
        </Grid.Row>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
};

MealList.propTypes = {
  cat: PropTypes.string,
};

MealList.defaultProps = {
  cat: '',
};

export default MealList;
```